# Wine on Gentoo fails with libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed message

Tags: linux, wine, gentoo, gcc, glibc

Not long ago problems with Wine have began on my Gentoo PC... When I try to launch any application I see this thing:

```
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
wine client error:25: write: Неправильный дескриптор файла (RU>EN translation: Unknown file descriptor)
```

For example I try to run this command:

```
wine rview34.exe
```

And I get this output:

```
stan@morpheus ~/Downloads $ wine rview34ru.exe 
err:menubuilder:write_freedesktop_association_entry error writing association file "/home/stan/.local/share/applications/wine-extension-chm.desktop"
err:menubuilder:write_freedesktop_association_entry error writing association file "/home/stan/.local/share/applications/wine-extension-gif.desktop"
err:menubuilder:write_freedesktop_association_entry error writing association file "/home/stan/.local/share/applications/wine-extension-hlp.desktop"
err:menubuilder:write_freedesktop_association_entry error writing association file "/home/stan/.local/share/applications/wine-extension-htm.desktop"
err:menubuilder:write_freedesktop_association_entry error writing association file "/home/stan/.local/share/applications/wine-extension-ini.desktop"
err:menubuilder:write_freedesktop_association_entry error writing association file "/home/stan/.local/share/applications/wine-extension-jfif.desktop"
err:menubuilder:write_freedesktop_association_entry error writing association file "/home/stan/.local/share/applications/wine-extension-jpe.desktop"
err:menubuilder:write_freedesktop_association_entry error writing association file "/home/stan/.local/share/applications/wine-extension-msp.desktop"
err:menubuilder:write_freedesktop_association_entry error writing association file "/home/stan/.local/share/applications/wine-extension-png.desktop"
err:menubuilder:write_freedesktop_association_entry error writing association file "/home/stan/.local/share/applications/wine-extension-rtf.desktop"
err:menubuilder:write_freedesktop_association_entry error writing association file "/home/stan/.local/share/applications/wine-extension-txt.desktop"
err:menubuilder:write_freedesktop_association_entry error writing association file "/home/stan/.local/share/applications/wine-extension-url.desktop"
err:menubuilder:write_freedesktop_association_entry error writing association file "/home/stan/.local/share/applications/wine-extension-wri.desktop"
err:menubuilder:write_freedesktop_association_entry error writing association file "/home/stan/.local/share/applications/wine-extension-xml.desktop"
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
wine client error:25: write: Неправильный дескриптор файла
```

Here are the versions of various pieces of software, that I think should be related to the problem...

```
sys-devel/binutils-2.22-r1
app-emulation/wine-1.4.1
sys-devel/gcc-4.7.2
sys-libs/glibc-2.15-r3
sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-3.6.6
```

Actually everything worked perfectly some day ago, I used to work with Radmin Viewer just fine. Latest updates were **linux-headers** and **open-rc** I believe.

I'm trying to remember when the problem occured, but it's actually hard to do so... I don't use Wine often... One of the things that caused the problem could be:

```
emerge -aveDN --with-bdeps=y system
```

I also have tried to reinstall software listed above, first of all I've even deleted the **.wine** folder, but it didn't help...

I was Googling for an answer for about 3-4 days, still no luck... Then I came here for help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what helped me to fix the problem:

```
cd /lib32
ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/32/libgcc_s.so.1 libgcc_s.so.1
```

But I guess it's not the right way, instead I should do something with GCC path configurations...

Answer (score 0):

I have not been on Gentoo for a long time, but seams like you are missing libgcc. Try installing it with emerge - or search for it through emerge to find the package name it is included in. Then install and try to run Wine again.

Comment: The lib is installed with gcc. I've re-emerged it 2 times already, no luck... But the lib DOES exist, and it's located in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/` folder.
libgcc_s.so.1 (file)
libgcc_s.so -> libgcc_s.so.1 (link)

Comment: Are you trying to run 32bit code?
Try installing lib32gcc1.. Does that help?

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow. The problem appeared on the PC I use at work, which has 64-bit OS installed, at home with 32-bit OS everything is OK with Wine, even after `emerge -e world`. I also think that GCC version could be a problem, at work I'm using the one that was heavily masked to unlock `march=core-avx-i` that comes with GCC 4.7.x. At home I use GCC 4.6.3. But the thing is - it worked just fine at work also!

Comment: Maybe you had the 32bit gcc libs installed at work, and emerge for some reason removed them. It could be the version, but I doubt it - Seams like everyone having this problem are trying to run 32bit software with 64bit gcc libs - and a lot solves it by installing 32bit. Let me know if it works for you tomorrow :)